# iOS: In `UIScrollView`'s delegate,I want to change `grey color` to `green color` by gradual changing

Tags: ios, uicolor

I have tried in my code to gradual change `textColor` in `UIScrollView`'s delegate:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{

    CGFloat rightScale = scrollView.contentOffset.x / [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width;
    //  0~1
    rightScale = rightScale - leftI;

    CGFloat leftScale = 1 - rightScale;

    // #define APP_COLOR RGB(30, 170, 61)
    [leftLabel setTextColor:kColor( leftScale * 30 / 255.0 , leftScale *170 / 255.0,  leftScale *61 / 255.0)];
    [rigthLabel setTextColor:kColor(rightScale * 30 / 255.0, rightScale * 170 / 255.0, rightScale  * 61 / 255.0)];
}
```

In the result I can only change `black color` to my `APP_COLOR`, but I want to change a `custom color` to `APP_COLOR`,I don't know the answer off the top of my stupid head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have thought of this `question's`answer:

I take the `key codes` below to resolve my question:

```
 [leftLabel setTextColor:kColor( (leftScale * 30 + rightScale * 122.5) / 255.0 , (leftScale *170 + rightScale * 122.5)/ 255.0,  (leftScale *61 + rightScale * 122.5) / 255.0)];
 [rigthLabel setTextColor:kColor((rightScale * 30  + leftScale * 122.5) / 255.0, (rightScale * 170 + leftScale * 122.5) / 255.0, (rightScale  * 61  + leftScale * 122.5) / 255.0)];
```